# How can I avoid cross reference among dimensions in a nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, function, nested

I have to do some operations with matrices (nested arrays) and I've encountered a 'funny' situation that I'm not sure why it's happening.
I have these two functions:

```js
function createNDMatrix(
    dimensions_lengths: number[],
    fill_value: number | null = null
): any {
    if (dimensions_lengths.length === 1) {
        return Array(dimensions_lengths[0]).fill(fill_value);
    } else {
        return Array(dimensions_lengths[dimensions_lengths.length - 1]).fill(
            createNDMatrix(dimensions_lengths.slice(0, dimensions_lengths.length - 1), fill_value)
        );
    }
}
function nestedFill(
    array_to_fill: any,
    position_to_fill: number[],
    fill_value: number | null
): void {
    if (position_to_fill.length === 1) {
        array_to_fill[position_to_fill[0]] = fill_value;
    } else {
        nestedFill(
            array_to_fill[position_to_fill[position_to_fill.length - 1]],
            position_to_fill.slice(0, position_to_fill.length - 1),
            fill_value
        );
    }
}
```

`createNDMatrix` allows me to create an arbitrary nested matrix such that `createNDMatrix([2, 2, 2], null)` => `[[[null, null],[null, null]],[[null, null],[null, null]]]` and `nestedFill` allows me to fill an arbitrary nested (provided) matrix such that `nestedFill([[[null, null],[null, null]],[[null, null],[null, null]]], [0, 1, 1], 10)` => `[[[null, null],[null, null]],[[null, null],[10, null]]]`

Up to here everything behaves as I expected; both functions are recursive, but the way the `nestedFill` function fills the matrix, and the way that `createNDMatrix` creates the matrix makes me think that the dimensions inside of them shouldn't be pointing at each other. However, when I do `nestedFill(createNDMatrix([2, 2, 2], null), 10)` I get as a result `[ [ [ 10, null ], [ 10, null ] ], [ [ 10, null ], [ 10, null ] ] ]`, which I don't understand why it happens.

Obviously there is something wrong with the `createNDMatrix` function when filling in arrays recursively, but I can't understand why. Does anybody know why this happens?
[Here is a working demonstration of my problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-meadow-k9mjq)

Comment: Don't pass non-primitives to `.fill`, use `Array.from` instead

Comment: @P.Gracia  If you do this -> `var x = Array(10).fill([1,2,3])`,  your array will basically be filled with 10 identical array's, arrays that are using the same memory location.  Arrays in JS are Object's, so are copied by reference.  IOW:  `x[0], x[1],..` all point to the same array.  A simple solution to this is just fill the array with anything, and then map.  eg.  `var x = Array(10).fill(undefined).map(f => [1,2,3])`,  Here is an updated sandbox doing that -> https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-surf-1tj90?file=/src/index.ts